# Show Output In Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am very new in SQL and i need a output like this. 
I have a table

```
Name    Price 
----------------
A        10    
B        20   
C        30
```

and output should be

```
Name    Price    running  
--------------------------
A       10          10    
B       20          30  
C       30          60
```

Please Tell me the Query for this output.

Comment: can u post the whole table...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Comment: tell more about the running field! whats that?

Comment: i have to show that on run time... i have only single table

Comment: This is a very good article regarding the Running Total problem. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/. Also, if you were using SQL Server 2012, there is another solution you could use that involves `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
select t1.Name, t1.Price,
    SUM(t2.Price) as running
    from your_table t1 inner join your_table t2
on t1.Name >= t2.Name
group by t1.Name, t1.Price
order by t1.Name
```

### [Demo SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3a14/2)

Comment: but i have only single table

Comment: They both are the same table..@user1648801

Comment: Just be aware that some collations treat characters differently so it may not always be A < B < C etc. In most cases, this is not a problem.