# SUM subset of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, cumulative-sum

I have a question about creating a running total on an existing query in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Basically, I have a query that combines data from 3 separate tables and groups them to produce a single entry for each combination of `ACCOUNT`, `PROFITCENTRE`, `TIMEID` and `DIVISION`

However, I need to alter the values in `SIGNEDDATA`, such that each entry is the total of all previous months.

e.g.

- `TIMEID` 20120300 (March 2012) would contain -35143.0000000000
- `TIMEID` 20120400 (April 2012) should then contain -36000.0000000000 (March plus the -857 for April)
- `TIMEID` 20120500 (May 2012) should be -36857.0000000000, etc.,

Rather than what I currently get, which is the sum of `SIGNEDDATA` for each month, grouped by `ACCOUNT, PROFITCENTRE, DIVISION`, etc, but not added to previous months.

How can I do this, as I have tried removing `TIMEID` from the `GROUP BY` clause, but I just get the usual error about not being able to retrieve the column as it is not contained in either an aggregate or Group by......?

My selection is as follows:

```
Insert INTO Data_Services.dbo.[NEW_TABLE] 
Select
[Account],
[Category],
[DataSrc],
[ProfitCentre],
'MY_FLOW' as [Flow],
[RptCurrency],
[TimeID],
sum(round([SignedData],2,0)) as SignedData,
[Division],
@CurrentTime as CTimeID
FROM
(select 
    T1.[Account],
    T1.[Category],
    T1.[DataSrc],
    T1.[ProfitCentre],
    T1.[Flow],
    T1.[RptCurrency],
    T1.[TimeID],
    sum(round(T1.[SignedData],2,0)) as SignedData,
    mbrPC.[Division]
from 
         MY_DATABASE.dbo.TABLE1 T1
    join 
         MY_DATABASE.dbo.mbrProfitCentre mbrPC on T1.ProfitCentre = mbrPC.[ID]
where   
        T1.Category = 'WForecast'
        and T1.DataSrc in (SELECT [ID] from DSParent)
        and T1.Flow = 'MOVEMENT'
        and T1.Account in 
            (SELECT [ID] from AccIEParent)
        and TimeID in 
        (select [TimeID] from MY_DATABASE.dbo.mbrTime
        where   [Period_Start] <> ''
        and [Period_Start] is not null
        and convert(date,[Period_Start],101) <= '2013-01-24'
        and [CURRYEAR] = 'Y')

group by    T1.[Account],
        T1.[Category],
        T1.[DataSrc],
        T1.[ProfitCentre],
        T1.[Flow],
        T1.[RptCurrency],
        T1.[TimeID],
        mbrPC.[Division]

UNION

select 
    T2.[Account],
    T2.[Category],
    T2.[DataSrc],
    T2.[ProfitCentre],
    T2.[Flow],
    T2.[RptCurrency],
    T2.[TimeID],
    sum(round(T2.[SignedData],2,0)) as SignedData,
    mbrPC.[Division]

from MY_DATABASE.dbo.TABLE2 T2
    join MY_DATABASE.dbo.mbrProfitCentre mbrPC
        on T2.ProfitCentre = mbrPC.[ID]


where   T2.Category = 'WForecast'
    and T2.DataSrc in 
            (SELECT [ID] from DSParent)
    and T2.Flow = 'MOVEMENT'
    and T2.Account in 
            (SELECT [ID] from AccIEParent)
    and TimeID in 
        (select [TimeID] from MY_DATABASE.dbo.mbrTime
        where   [Period_Start] <> ''
        and [Period_Start] is not null
        and convert(date,[Period_Start],101) <= '2013-01-24'
        and [CURRYEAR] = 'Y')

group by    T2.[Account],
        T2.[Category],
        T2.[DataSrc],
        T2.[ProfitCentre],
        T2.[Flow],
        T2.[RptCurrency],
        T2.[TimeID],
        mbrPC.[Division]

UNION

select 
    T3.[Account],
    T3.[Category],
    T3.[DataSrc],
    T3.[ProfitCentre],
    T3.[Flow],
    T3.[RptCurrency],
    T3.[TimeID],
    sum(round(T3.[SignedData],2,0)) as SignedData,
    mbrPC.[Division]

from MY_DATABASE.dbo.TABLE3 T3
    join MY_DATABASE.dbo.mbrProfitCentre mbrPC
        on T3.ProfitCentre = mbrPC.[ID]

where   T3.Category = 'WForecast'
    and T3.DataSrc in 
            (SELECT [ID] from DSParent)
    and T3.Flow = 'MOVEMENT'
    and T3.Account in 
            (SELECT [ID] from AccIEParent)
    and TimeID in 
        (select [TimeID] from MY_DATABASE.dbo.mbrTime
        where   [Period_Start] <> ''
        and [Period_Start] is not null
        and convert(date,[Period_Start],101) <= '2013-01-24'
        and [CURRYEAR] = 'Y')

group by    T3.[Account],
        T3.[Category],
        T3.[DataSrc],
        T3.[ProfitCentre],
        T3.[Flow],
        T3.[RptCurrency],
        T3.[TimeID],
        mbrPC.[Division]
) a

group by    [Account],
        [Category],
        [DataSrc],
        [ProfitCentre],
        [Flow],
        [RptCurrency],
        [TimeID],
        [Division]
```

And the resulting data-set is:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get cumulative sum](/q/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is slightly more complex than the examples in this ticket but there are answers here with various methods of calculating a cumulative sum.

[how to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Comment: Thanks Justin.  I was able to use a staging table to aggregate the data once, then create the cumulative totals by using the information in the post that you suggested.  Maybe not the most streamlined way, but as it only takes 4 seconds and it's only once a day, that's fine.