# Recursive function in SQL

Tags: sql, function, recursion

i have the data in my table as follows,

```
+----+-----+
| ID | Qty |
+----+-----+
|  1 | 100 |
|  2 | 200 |
|  3 | 150 |
|  4 |  50 |
+----+-----+
```

i need the result as follows,

```
+----+-----+-------+
| ID | Qty | C.Qty |
+----+-----+-------+
|  1 | 100 |   100 |
|  2 | 200 |   300 |
|  3 | 150 |   450 |
|  4 |  50 |   500 |
+----+-----+-------+
```

the result of third column will be the sum of previous rows,
please any one help....

Comment: I don't understand...where does the `500` come from?

Comment: @PaulDraper 450+50=500..

Comment: It' already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Comment: Oh...he meant previous *rows*, not columns. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a subquery:

```
SELECT ID, Qty,
   (SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM [My Table] b WHERE b.ID <= [My Table].ID) AS [Total Qty]
FROM [My Table]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
SELECT S1.ID, S1.Qty ,sum(S2.Qty) CUM_SUM
FROM YourTable S1 join YourTable S2
on S1.ID>=S2.ID
group by S1.ID, S1.Qty
ORDER BY S1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT ID, Qty,
 SUM(Qty) OVER(ORDER BY ID 
 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
      AS C.QTY
 FROM Table
```

Comment: Looks interesting.  What database server is this for?

Comment: @David Sql Server 2012 (not supported prior). Not sure when oracle started supporting it. Works in at least 11g. Wouldn't be surprised if it worked postgresql. Definitely won't work in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select a.id,a.qty,sum(b.qty) as total_qty
from table a cross join table b
where b.id <= a.id
group by a.id,a.qty 
order by a.id
```

[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b459e/1)