# Cumulative Sum (to calculate production) in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query (below) that show me data in the column and I need cumulative production

```
DATE      SHIFT  PRODUCTI SUM
1/1/2013  A      300      300
1/1/2013  B      301      601
1/1/2013  C      325      926
2/1/2013  A      568      1494
2/1/2013  B      256      1750
2/1/2013  C      580      2330
3/1/2013  A      645      2975
3/1/2013  B      235      3210
3/1/2013  C      236      3446
```

Comment: Sum for what?All rows?For each Shift group or date group?

Comment: which version of TSQL ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Answer (score 1):

Should just be
Select sum(production) from tablename

Comment: No, you must put a conditional SUM

Comment: this should be a  comment, not an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.date, t1.shift, t1.production, 
(SELECT SUM(t2.production) from table t2
WHERE t2.date = t1.date AND t2.shift <= t1.shift 
OR t2.date < t1.date)
FROM table t1
```

Tell me if it's OK

[Here you find your Sql Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cca23/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.PRODUCTION, SUM(t2.SomeNumt) as sum
from @t t1
inner join @t t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.SomeNumt
order by t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work in sqlserver 2012+

```
SELECT *, SUM(PRODUCTI) OVER (ORDER BY DATE, SHIFT) [SUM]
FROM @t
```