# SQL - how to retrieve aggregation result under condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

for example - given the table `players`

```
id name date      deposit
1  tom  1.1.2014  30
2  roy  2.1.2014  40
3  tom  2.1.2014  80
4  liat 4.1.2014  105
5  tom  6.1.2014  30
```

retrieve players `names`,`date` and the sum of deposit of the players who passed the 100 deposit. (the `date` should be the `day` that the player passed `100`)
in the example the result should be:

```
tom  2.1.2014 110  
liat 4.1.2014 105
```

thanks
roy

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: sorry for the late respond:    sql server

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but this is ANSI (standard) SQL:

```
with summed as (
  select name, 
         date, 
         sum(deposit) over (partition by name order by date) as deposit
  from players
)
select s1.*
from summed s1
where s1.total_deposit > 100
  and s1.date = (select min(date)
                 from summed s2
                 where s2.name = s1.name
                   and s2.total_deposit > 100)
order by name;
```

It seems that (at least with Postgres) this is more efficient (but with such a tiny data set this is really hard to tell):

```
with summed as (
  select name, 
         date, 
         sum(deposit) over (partition by name order by date) as deposit
  from players
), numbered as (
  select s1.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by name order by date) as rn
  from summed s1
  where s1.deposit >= 100
)
select name, date, deposit
from numbered
where rn = 1
order by name;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d4590/13

But Uri's solution is probably still more efficient with proper indexing.

---

<sup>Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it is a reserved word, but more importantly it doesn't document what the column contains. A "played date"? A "due date"? A "deposit date"? A "valid until" date?</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a database that support cumulative sum, you can start with:

```
select p.*,
       sum(p.deposit) over (partition by p.name order by p.date) as cumedeposit,
       sum(p.deposit) over (partition by p.name) as totdeposit
from players p;
```

The following gets the information about when a player crosses the 100 deposit mark:

```
select p.name, p.date, p.totdeposit
from (select p.*,
             sum(p.deposit) over (partition by p.name order by p.date) as cumedeposit,
             sum(p.deposit) over (partition by p.name) as totdeposit
      from players p
     ) p
where cumedeposit >= 100 and cumdeposit - deposit < 100;
```

If your database does not support cumulative sums and/or window functions, you can do pretty much the same thing with correlated subqueries.

Comment: That's probably more efficient than my solution. Only a single scan over the table required.

Answer (score 0):

Use this technique to calculate [cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum) in SQL

```
SELECT p.name, p.date,p.cumsum as total_deposit FROM
(
select t1.name, t1.date, SUM(t2.deposit) as cumsum
from players t1
inner join players t2 on t1.date >= t2.date and and t1.name = t2.nam
group by t1.name, t1.date
) p
WHERE p.cumsum>100
GROUP BY p.name
HAVING  p.date=MIN(p.date)
```

Comment: it needs to return the amount too

Comment: WHERE p.cumsum>100 AND p.date=MIN(p.date) will throw an error

Comment: if you group by p.name then you need to aggregate any other row in the select otherwise it will also throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p1.name,sum(p1.deposit) as deposit , (select p2.date from players p2 where p2.id = p1.id) 
from players p1 where p1.deposit >= 100
group by p1.id,p1.name
```