# Select x rows from table having total < y SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have `Table A` with the following data:

```
Id  Value
1   100
2   63
4   50
6   24
7   446
```

I want to select the first rows with a `SUM(value) <= 200`.

So the desired output should be:

```
Id Value
1   100
4   50
6   24
```

Comment: Which version of sql-server? In 2012 you can use ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING to get the cumulative sum. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Comment: @TimSchmelter, seems OP wants to get `Value` less then or equal to 200 only, not cumulative sum.

Comment: `SELECT Id, Value FROM TableName WHERE Value <=200`

Comment: I think you need to add few more values into your data sample to make it more clear. now it is confusing.

Comment: i mean that the total of the values is <=200 not just value<=200

Comment: Will  the 6 people that up voted this please read [Should I be careful when upvoting questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302331/578411)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should return expected result:

```
WITH TableWithTotals AS
(SELECT 
 id, 
 value,
 SUM (Value) OVER (ORDER BY Value, Id) as total
FROM myTable)
SELECT * FROM TableWithTotals
WHERE total <=200;
```

This code will maximise the number of records that fit under 200 limit as running total is calculated over ordered values.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/139ce/4)

Comment: well, the problem with my original answer was that OVER cannot be used in WHERE, that is easily fixable via CTE, idea is the same.

Comment: Thnx this is want i wanted , sorry if my question was unclear :)

Comment: @Bulat: but it's a duplicate answer of Gareth's anyway

Comment: I agree, that is why up-voted his answer. @user1753385 if you accept Gareth's answer, I will delete mine.

Answer (score 8):

**SIMPLE ANSWER**

You need to find the Cumulative Sum for each row, and since you want as many rows as possible, you need to start with the lowest value (`ORDER BY Value`):

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  Id, 
            Value,
            CumulativeValue = SUM(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Value, Id)
    --FROM  (VALUES (1, 100), (2, 300), (4, 50), (6, 24), (7, 446)) AS t (Id, Value)
    FROM    TableA AS t
)
SELECT  d.Id, d.Value
FROM    Data AS d
WHERE   d.CumulativeValue <= 200
ORDER BY d.Id;
```

**COMPLETE ANSWER**

If you want to be more selective about which rows you choose that have a sum of less than 200 then it gets a bit more complicated for example, in your new sample data:

```
Id  Value
1   100
2   63
4   50
6   24
7   446
```

There are 3 different combinations that allow for a total of less than 200:

```
Id  Value
1   100
2   63
6   24

--> 187

Id  Value
2   63
4   50
6   24

--> 137

Id  Value
1   100
4   50
6   24

--> 174
```

The only way to do this is to get all combinations that have a sum less than 200, then choose the combination that you want, in order to do this you will need to use a recursive common table expression to get all combinations:

```
WITH TableA AS
(   SELECT  Id, Value
    FROM    (VALUES (1, 100), (2, 63), (4, 50), (6, 24), (7, 446)) t (Id, Value)
), CTE AS
(   SELECT  Id,
            IdList = CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
            CumulativeValue = Value,
            ValueCount = 1
    FROM    TableA AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  T.ID, 
            IdList = CTE.IDList + ',' + CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
            CumulativeValue = CTE.CumulativeValue + T.Value,
            ValueCount = CTE.ValueCount + 1
    FROM    CTE
            INNER JOIN TableA AS T
                ON ',' + CTE.IDList + ',' NOT LIKE '%,' + CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',%'
                AND CTE.ID < T.ID
    WHERE   T.Value + CTE.CumulativeValue <= 200
)
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE
ORDER BY ValueCount DESC, CumulativeValue DESC;
```

This outputs (with single rows removed)

```
Id  IdList  CumulativeValue ValueCount
-------------------------------------
6   1,2,6       187         3
6   1,4,6       174         3
6   2,4,6       137         3
2   1,2         163         2
4   1,4         150         2
6   1,6         124         2
4   2,4         113         2
6   2,6         87          2
6   4,6         74          2
```

So you need to choose which combination of rows best meets your requirements, for example if you wanted, as described before, the most number of rows with a value as close to 200 as possible, then you would need to choose the top result, if you wanted the lowest total, then you would need to change the ordering.

Then you can get your original output by using `EXISTS` to get the records that exist in `IdList`:

```
WITH TableA AS
(   SELECT  Id, Value
    FROM    (VALUES (1, 100), (2, 63), (4, 50), (6, 24), (7, 446)) t (Id, Value)
), CTE AS
(   SELECT  Id,
            IdList = CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
            CumulativeValue = Value,
            ValueCount = 1
    FROM    TableA AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  T.ID, 
            IdList = CTE.IDList + ',' + CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)),
            CumulativeValue = CTE.CumulativeValue + T.Value,
            ValueCount = CTE.ValueCount + 1
    FROM    CTE
            INNER JOIN TableA AS T
                ON ',' + CTE.IDList + ',' NOT LIKE '%,' + CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',%'
                AND CTE.ID < T.ID
    WHERE   T.Value + CTE.CumulativeValue <= 200
), Top1 AS
(   SELECT  TOP 1 IdList, CumulativeValue
    FROM    CTE
    ORDER BY ValueCount DESC, CumulativeValue DESC -- CHANGE TO MEET YOUR NEEDS
)
SELECT  *
FROM    TableA AS t
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Top1
            WHERE   ',' + Top1.IDList + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',%'
        );
```

This is not very efficient, but I can't see a better way at the moment.

This returns

```
Id  Value
1   100
2   63
6   24
```

This is the closest to 200 you can get with the most possible rows. Since there are multiple ways of achieving "x number of rows that have a sum of less than 200", there are also multiple ways of writing the query. You would need to be more specific about what your preference of combination is in order to get the exact answer you need.

Comment: Your code seem to work fine but this part   FROM    (VALUES (1, 100), (2, 300), (4, 50), (6, 24), (7, 446)) AS t (Id, Value)   i dont know how to select

Comment: @user1753385: that's just sample data. Replace it with your real table.

Comment: Why `ORDER BY Value, Id` and not just `ORDER BY Id` ? OP wants ti get all rows where the cumulative sum is <= 200 ordered by the ID. At least that is how i understood the question(_"select the first rows with a sum <=200"_).

Comment: WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  Id, 
            Value,
            CumulativeValue = SUM(Value) OVER(ORDER BY Value, Id)
    FROM    (select id,value from TableA)
)
SELECT  d.Id, d.Value
FROM    Data AS d
WHERE   d.CumulativeValue <= 200
ORDER BY d.Id;      i get this error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The cumulative totals in order of ID are `100, 163, 213, 237, 683`, therefore a filter of `<= 200` would only return the first two rows, and not add the third row of 24 in, and this does not match the OPs expected output.

Comment: @user1753385 I have updated the answer to remove the reference to sample data, and replaced it with `TableA`

Answer (score 1):

As per i understood your requirement, i think below query should be helpful to you.

```
WITH FinalResult AS
(SELECT 
 id, 
 value,
 SUM (Value) OVER (ORDER BY Value, Id) as ValueCount
FROM TableA)
SELECT * FROM FinalResult
WHERE ValueCount <=200;
```

Comment: This is not going to work. You have group by clause with out aggregate function in select.

Answer (score -1):

you  should try this:-

```
    SELECT Id, Value FROM TableName WHERE Value <=200
```

Comment: This does not provide the result the OP asked for, which is sum <= 200