# cumulative column in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using sql server 2012, where I have table [BonusTransactions]

```
(Id, Author, Bonus)
1    Andrew  5 
2    Andrew  2
3    Jim     6
4    Jim     2
5    Jim     15
```

I need to make query that will return this table with cumulative field for every Author:

```
(Id, Author, Bonus, TotalBonus)
1    Andrew  5      5  (5)
2    Andrew  2      7  (5+2)
3    Jim     6      6  (6)
4    Jim     2      8  (6 + 2)
5    Jim     15     23 (6 + 2 + 15)
```

So I tried this query:

```
SELECT  Id, Author, Bonus,
Sum(Bonus) Over (Partition By Author order by Id) as TotalBonus
FROM [dbo].[BonusTransactions]
```

but it doesn't work: 
"Incorrect syntax near 'order'."

Also i tried this:

```
SELECT  Id, Author, Bonus,
Sum(Bonus) Over (Partition By Author order by Id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as TotalBonus
FROM [dbo].[BonusTransactions]
```

But in this case intellisense highlights "ROWS BETWEEN" and column names

Comment: Check your compatibility level.  You may be using SQL Server 2012 but with compatibility set to an earlier version.  Here is a place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx.

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum.  It has solutions without window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably the compatibility level.  Either set it to 110 for SQL Server 2012, or use a construct available in earlier versions.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Author, t.Bonus, tt.TotalBonus
FROM [dbo].[BonusTransactions] t outer apply
     (SELECT Sum(t2.Bonus) as TotalBonus
      FROM [dbo].[BonusTransactions] t2
      WHERE t2.Author = t.Author AND t2.Id <= t.id
     ) tt;
```

Comment: After  
ALTER DATABASE MyBase
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110

Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100.

Comment: Also your query is executing too long

Comment: @AlexanderPidoprigora . . . Your question is tagged SQL Server 2012.  It would seem you have an earlier version.  The only thing you can help with the query is an index on `BonusTransactions(Author, id)`.