# Lead() and LAG() functionality in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression, lag, lead

Hope all the SQL GURUS out there are doing great :)

I am trying to simulate `LEAD()` and `LAG()` functionality in SQL Server 2008.

This is my scenario: I have a temp table which is populated using the base query with the business logic for mileage. I want to calculate accumulated mileage for each user per day.

The temp table is setup using `ROW_NUMBER()`, so I have all the data needed in the temp table except the accumulated mileage.

I have tried using a CTE with the base query and self joining with itself and couldn't get it working. I am attaching the screen shot for the same.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a96f/3   few options found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Comment: Since you are doing a daily diff, can't you join the table onto itself with A.Date = DateAdd(Day,1,B.Date) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track by joining the table to itself. I included 2 methods of doing this below that should work fine here. The first trick is in your `ROW_NUMBER`, be sure to partition by the user id and sort by the date. Then you can use either an `INNER JOIN` with aggregation or `CROSS APPLY` to build your running totals.

**Setting up the data with the partitioned `ROW_NUMBER()`:**

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    RowNum INT,
    UserId INT,
    Date DATE,
    Miles INT
)
INSERT @Data 
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId
            ORDER BY Date) AS RowNum,
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT 1, '2015-01-01', 5
        UNION ALL SELECT 1, '2015-01-02', 6
        UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2015-01-01', 7
        UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2015-01-02', 3
        UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2015-01-03', 2
        ) T (UserId, Date, Miles)
```

**Use `INNER JOIN` with Aggregation**

```
SELECT
    D1.UserId,
    D1.Date,
    D1.Miles,
    SUM(D2.Miles) AS [Total]
FROM @Data D1
    INNER JOIN @Data D2
        ON D1.UserId = D2.UserId
            AND D2.RowNum <= D1.RowNum
GROUP BY
    D1.UserId,
    D1.Date,
    D1.Miles
```

**Use `CROSS APPLY` for the running total**

```
SELECT
    UserId,
    Date,
    Miles,
    Total
FROM @Data D1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT SUM(Miles) AS Total
        FROM @Data
        WHERE UserId = D1.UserId
            AND RowNum <= D1.RowNum
    ) RunningTotal
```

**Output is the same for each method:**

```
UserId      Date       Miles       Total
----------- ---------- ----------- -----------
1           2015-01-01 5           5
1           2015-01-02 6           11
2           2015-01-01 7           7
2           2015-01-02 3           10
2           2015-01-03 2           12
```