# Refer to previous computed column in SQL

Tags: sql, excel, select

I am trying to calculate the val column using id column and the previous val column. On Excel, I simply use the formula "=IF(B2=1,1,C1+B2)". How can i reference previous value of my column being computed?

```
id  val
1   1
2   3
3   6
4   10
5   15
6   21
7   28
8   36
9   45
10  55
```

My query would look like

```
SELECT id,
Case
 When id =1 then 1
 Else id+*previousval*
 end as val
from 
tab
```

Comment: May i know the DBMS and version of your SQL, it seems like running total problem ?

Comment: I find this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for **SQL Server** (using variable will give you a best performance):

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Id INT, Val INT)

INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES(1,0)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES(2,0)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES(3,0)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES(4,0)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES(5,0)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES(6,0)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES(7,0)

DECLARE @PrevSum INT = 0

UPDATE @TempTable
SET @PrevSum = Val = @PrevSum + Id
FROM @TempTable

SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can tag your DBMS and its version..

Assuming that you are using SQL Server:

**SQL Server BELOW 2012** (*you can use the Common Table Expression - CTE*)

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST(ID INT)
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

;WITH CTE
as
(
   SELECT ID, ID AS VALUE FROM #TEST WHERE ID=1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT T.ID, T.ID + C.VALUE
   FROM #TEST T INNER JOIN CTE C ON T.ID = C.ID+1
)

SELECT * FROM CTE

DROP TABLE #TEST
```

[SQL Fiddle for version 2012 Below](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe480/1)

**SQL Server 2012:** (you can use `OVER` clause)

```
CREATE TABLE #Test(ID INT)

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)

SELECT id, SUM(id) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS [Value] FROM #Test ORDER BY id

DROP TABLE #Test
```

[SQL Fiddle: SQL Server 2012](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20acf/5)