# how to sum tow field at get inline result?

Tags: sql

i have tow field for example credit an debit in one table.
and i need to sum them and get result at each line for example :

```
date          debit   credit  amount
2015/01/01     20       0        20
2015/01/02      0       5        15
2015/01/03      0       30      -15
```

i hope you help me to get the amount by a query
thanks

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: What dbms? (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQL-Server 2012 or newer you can use this:

```
SELECT [date], debit, credit, amount,
   SUM(debit-credit) OVER(ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS amount
FROM TableName
ORDER BY [date]
```

Read: [`OVER`-clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.110).aspx), especially the `ROWS | RANGE` part

With other versions you have to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT [date], debit, credit, amount,
  (SELECT SUM(debit-credit) 
   FROM TableName t2
   WHERE [date] <= t1.[date]) AS amount
FROM TableName t1
ORDER BY [date]
```

Comment: this code help me very well.but i have another problem how can i filter date and get true result for example i filter date from 2015/01/02 and i want get the result -15 in my amount could you help me whit this?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim's answer, I added some extra lines:

```
declare @credit as table (
    [date] datetime,
    amount int
)

declare @debit as table (
    [date] datetime,
    amount int
)

insert into @debit values 
    ('2015-01-01', 20)

insert into @credit values 
    ('2015-01-02', 5),
    ('2015-01-03', 30)


select
    [date], debit, credit, SUM(debit-credit) OVER(ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS amount
from(
    select 
        [date], sum(debit) debit, sum(credit) credit
    from
    (
    select 
        [date], 0 credit, d.amount debit
    from
        @debit d
    union all
    select 
        [date], c.amount credit, 0 debit
    from
        @credit c
    ) j group by j.date
) x
```