# how to add data two colums add after add two add next

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have following query i want add two records like 16+16 = 32 + 15 = 47 like this i wANT 30 + 15 , = 47 + 15 like this ,

```
WITH    rows AS
        (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY gps_time) AS rn
        FROM    rawtTackHistory_A2Z where car_id = 12956 
        )
SELECT  mc.gps_time,DATEDIFF(second, mc.gps_time, mp.gps_time)
FROM    rows mc
JOIN    rows mp
ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you are describing.  Can you provide desired results?

Comment: i want add 16 + 16 = 32  and then plus scond value like 32+ 15  then  47 + 15

Comment: dear i want add new column and, this column have sum values of timediff

Comment: You can use a calculator to add numbers.  Do you want to add rows to the table?  Do you want a query that returns 32?  I'm really not following.  Desired results would help a lot.

Comment: yesmi have edit some details

Comment: One suspects that you have some rule for the calculation.  I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you want a cumulative sum.  That's a question that's been answered already:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120639/2565840

EDIT: in your case I think the query below should work

```
WITH    
rows AS (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY gps_time) AS rn
        FROM    rawtTackHistory_A2Z where car_id = 12956 
),
differences AS (
    SELECT  mc.rn, mc.gps_time,DATEDIFF(second, mc.gps_time, mp.gps_time) time_diff
    FROM    rows mc
    JOIN    rows mp
    ON      mc.rn = mp.rn - 1
)
SELECT t1.gps_time, t1.time_diff, SUM(t2.time_diff) time_sum
FROM differences t1
INNER JOIN differences t2 
ON t1.rn >= t2.rn
GROUP BY t1.rn, t1.gps_time, t1.time_diff
ORDER BY t1.rn
```

or if you're using SQL Server 2012 or later,  this should run quicker:

```
SELECT gps_time
     , DATEDIFF(second, LAG(gps_time) OVER (ORDER BY gps_time), gps_time) time_diff
     , DATEDIFF(second, MIN(gps_time) OVER (ORDER BY gps_time), gps_time) time_sum
FROM rawtTackHistory_A2Z 
ORDER BY gps_time
```

It's using a windowing clause (`OVER`).  More detail here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: dear i want add new column and, this column have sum values of timediff

Comment: I've added an example.  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: error Column 'differences.time_diff' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: dear i have 100000 records its to slow and continuously  execution query

Comment: I've added an alternative method, which will work in SQL Server 2012 and later using a windowing clause

Comment: please do me a favor i want add CASE where i add this because if moving status stop ones again, else start