# Sql Query to calculate Salary till particular month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have as table as given below:

```
EmpID  SalaryMonth Salary
1       January    20000
1       February   15000
1       March      25000
```

I need to write a query to calculate salary till each month and output will be as given below. Each month salary will be added till last month salary.

```
EmpID  SalaryMonth Salary
1       January    20000
1       February   35000
1       March      60000
```

I tried solution using cursor but do we have any other solution by which we can achieve this.

Comment: Check comments on this link https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic873124-338-1.aspx I hope this might help.

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen Look above at the second formatted table.  This is the expected output, a rolling sum of salaries.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ahh I see. Thought its the same as sample the sample Data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

```
select EmpID,SalaryMonth,SUM(Salary) OVER(ORDER BY EmpID desc 
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
          AS Salary
  FROM t
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f62b/1)

Comment: This is the answer assuming you are using a newer version of SQL Server (IIRC 2012 forwards)

Comment: This won't work because you have no ordering for the dates.  Hence, I expect the rolling sum to be meaningless.

Comment: @vijaykumar Hadalgi 
The user may wants to sum the salaries by month wise based on
different empid.your query will not group the salaries based on empid.

Comment: Yes i can't try as i don't have updated version. So looking for some general solution. It will work for me even if it works for single ID .

Answer (score 0):

Please use "cumulative-sum" Like

select t1.id, t1.SomeNumt, SUM(t2.SomeNumt) as sum
from @t t1
inner join @t t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.SomeNumt
order by t1.id

Source:  [how to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Answer (score 0):

Try This it will help you

```
select * into #emp_sal from
(
select 1 EmpID      ,'January'as SalaryMonth,    20000 Salary
union all
select 1   , 'February',   15000
union all
select  1       ,'March',      25000
union all
select  2       ,'January',      30000
union all
select  2       ,'February',      8000
)as a

select EmpID,  SalaryMonth ,Salary,
sum(Salary)over(partition by empid order by SalaryMonth rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)as Actual_Salary 
from #emp_sal
```

Comment: As given above as well these methods are  available on newer version and i have sql server 2008. So looking for some general solution

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: You should *seriously* consider representing the `SalaryMonth` using a standard SQL Server date or timestamp column.  Using string month names creates all sorts of problems, hence my verbose answer below.

My approach is to use a CTE to assign a numerical position to each month name (`cte1`).  Then, I join this to your original table (`cte2`).  Finally, we can do a self join of `cte2` to compute the rolling salary over the course of the table.

There is probably a way to use the month names to create a date object of some sort, but I couldn't think of it, and in any case doing so would probably require assigning a dummy year, and possibly other things.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT 'January' AS SalaryMonth, 1 AS MonthPos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Februrary', 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'March', 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'April', 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'May', 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'June', 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'July', 7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'August', 8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'September', 9
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'October', 10
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'November', 11
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'December', 12
),
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT t1.EmpID,
           t1.SalaryMonth,
           t2.MonthPos,
           t1.Salary
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN cte1 t2
        ON t1.SalaryMonth = t2.SalaryMonth
)

SELECT t1.EmpID,
       t1.SalaryMonth,
       SUM(t2.Salary) AS Salary
FROM cte2 t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.MonthPos >= t2.MonthPos
GROUP BY t1.EmpID,
         t1.SalaryMonth
```