# how to add column value in next colum

Tags: sql, db2

```
id        value
1          10
2          20
3          30
4          40
5          50
```

Required output

table name data.

```
 id       value 
1         10    //( 10+0(previous value))
2         30   //( 20+10(previous value))
3         50   //( 30+20(previous value))
4         70   //( 40+30(previous value))
5         90    //(50+40(previous value))
```

please provide sql query

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using? mysql Or SQL Server?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: database name- ibm DB2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get cumulative sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `LAG` which is standard SQL and should be available in later DB2 versions if I'm not mistaken.

```
select
  id, 
  value + coalesce( lag(value) over (order by id), 0 ) as value
from mytable
order by id;
```

In case `LAG OVER` is not available, `SUM OVER` may be:

```
select
  id, 
  coalesce( sum(value) over (order by id rows between 1 preceding and current row), 0 )
    as value
from mytable
order by id;
```

Comment: when execute query than that error comes

select
  id, 
  coalesce( sum(value) over (order by id rows between 1 preceding and current row), 0 )
    as value
from users.mohit
order by id

"VALUE" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.18.60

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how it can come to this message. `value` is used in two places only: `sum(value)` which seems correct and `as value` which seems correct also. I don't know DB2 well. Does it have a problem, because we use the same name for the alias as for the column? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1:

```
select f1.id, 
ifnull((select f2.value from yourtable f2 where f1.id - 1 =f2.id), 0) + f1.value as value
from yourtable f1
```

Answer (score 0):

solution 2:

```
select f1.id, 
ifnull(f3.value, 0) + f1.value as value
from yourtable f1
left outer join lateral
(
    select f2.value from yourtable f2 
    where f1.id - 1 =f2.id
) f3 on 1=1
```