# Generate this output without using cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my table structure

```
 item |Transaction Type| Qty_IN | Qty Out |Transaction Sequence
------|----------------|--------|-----------------------
 item1| Beg. Balance   |   15   |    0    |  1
 item1| Received Item  |   5    |    0    |  2
 item1| Transfer Item  |   0    |    2    |  3
 item1| Transfer Item  |   0    |    3    |  4
```

My desired output

```
 item |Transaction Type| Qty_IN | Qty Out | End Bal
------|----------------|--------|---------|-------
 item1| Beg. Balance   |   0    |    0    |  15
 item1| Received Item  |   5    |    0    |  20
 item1| Transfer Item  |   0    |    2    |  18
 item1| Transfer Item  |   0    |    3    |  15
```

Is there another way to get my desired output without using cursor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Comment: I think the last two row of your *End Bal* of your **desired output** is should actually be `18` and `15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One standard way of obtaining a running balance is to use a correlated subquery in the select statement which computes the running sum of the difference between the in and out amounts:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.Qty_IN - t2.Qty_OUT) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.[Transaction Sequence] <= t1.[Transaction Sequence]) [End Bal]
FROM yourTable t1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!