# How to create a cumulative column based on another column

Tags: sql-server

I am extremely new to SQL Server 2012. I would like to create a new cumulative column however this column is only to be summed up for the distinct names.

For instance if i have the names with values below, i would like the repeated the corresponding values of the repeated names to be cumulatively summed up:

```
James        200
Vicky        300
Jane         600
James        400
Vicky        700
```

The end goal of the new column should have values that look like the values column below:

```
James     200
Vicky     300
Jane      600
James     600
Vicky     1000
```

Comment: If you need the cumulative sum, we need another column with the order of the rows,

Comment: Try this you might be able to achieve by adding name field on group by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Names VARCHAR(50), Value INT);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
    ('James', 200),
    ('Vicky', 300),
    ('Jane', 600),
    ('James', 400),
    ('Vicky', 700);

SELECT Names, SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITiON BY Names ORDER BY Value) Value
FROM @T
ORDER BY Value;
```

Result:

```
+=======+=======+
| Names | Value |
+=======+=======+
| James |   200 |
+-------+-------+
| Vicky |   300 |
+-------+-------+
| James |   600 |
+-------+-------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/TGLFX74922)**

Note: It's not in the same order, if you want the same order, you should do what @Lamak say in his comment, because we need that column.