# SQL accumulate of query with sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have this query in SQL:

```
select cast(faturas.datatotal as date) as Dia, faturas.sumF, credito.sumC, isnull(sumF,0)-isnull(sumC,0) as Total
from
(SELECT       SUM([Line Amount]) as sumF, [Posting Date] as datatotal
                               FROM            [CMW$Sales Invoice Line] 
                               where [CMW$Sales Invoice Line].[Posting Date] >= '2017-01-01' 
                               group by [CMW$Sales Invoice Line].[Posting Date]) faturas                   
full outer join
(SELECT        SUM(Amount) as sumC, [Posting Date]
                               FROM            [CMW$Sales Cr_Memo Line] 
                               where [CMW$Sales Cr_Memo Line].[Posting Date] >= '2017-01-01' 
                               group by [CMW$Sales Cr_Memo Line].[Posting Date]) credito                           
on faturas.datatotal=credito.[Posting Date]
```

I need to calculate the cumulative "Total" in this same query. How can I get this?

Comment: Can you copy and past your query to the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Comment: I see that answer Alex, but I could not successfully apply it in my case ... I'm still starting myself in sql

Comment: Why could you not apply the answer linked by Alex? What error where you getting? Also, in future, a screen shot of code is very difficult to work with. It's better to put the actual text in so people can copy and paste

Comment: I have already changed to text instead of image.
Maybe I was not able to use the answer suggested by my lack of knowledge in the area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this:

```
sum(isnull(sumF,0)-isnull(sumC,0)) over(order by faturas.datatotal rows unbounded preceding) as Acumulado
```

Thanks