# Need sql query for running totals

Tags: mysql

I have an application where the tasks are logged by the members:

```
task_id|task_date|task_name|task_duration
```

On a given day (`task_date`) there could be more than 1 tasks and sum total of the duration the tasks took collectively. Eg:

Table:2

```
task_date  | task_count | task_duration
2018-02-24 |    2       | 240
2018-02-25 |    1       | 100
2018-02-26 |    3       | 180
2018-02-27 |    2       | 60
```

I would like to draw a graph with cumulative figures so that I get a cumulative running total like this:

Desired output:

```
task_date  | task_count | task_duration
2018-02-24 |     2      | 240
2018-02-25 |     3      | 340
2018-02-26 |     6      | 520
2018-02-27 |     8      | 580
```

So that I can see the trend of tasks being logged and total time being spent of them.

Please focus on the Table:2 as the data to be worked on.

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh this question is about mysql, the link you posted is about sql-server.

Comment: @McNets But the answer does exactly what OP wants here too

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh but it is another RDBMS, MySql works completely diferent from SQL-Server for cumulative sums.

Comment: @McNets the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120639/2548147 in the link UdayrajDeshmukh posted is cross database (if you remove SQL-servers @ table sign) and should also work in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable for this job.

> ```
> select task_date, task_count, cum_sum
> from (select task_date, task_count, 
>              @cum := @cum + task_duration, @cum as cum_sum
>       from   tbl, (select @cum := 0) c) r
> ```
>
> ```
> task_date  | task_count | cum_sum
> :--------- | ---------: | :------
> 2018-02-24 |          2 | 240    
> 2018-02-25 |          1 | 340    
> 2018-02-26 |          3 | 520    
> 2018-02-27 |          2 | 580
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e8cea8a684430c8a3d25f2087a8855d8)*