# How to calculate the cumulative sum in SQL over rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL table:

```
StockID  Flow   Stock
1        +      2
1        -      3
1        +      8
```

I have another table:

```
ID   InStock
1    22
2    51
3    92
```

I want to select the first value of the second table `22` and add or subtract it cumulatively from  the values `Stock` of the first table with the `StockID = ID`, based on the sign in the flow column. Then add/subtract the values in the column `Stock` from this solution.

This should appear in a new column `Sol`:

```
ID    Flow   Stock    Sol
1      +      2        24    (22+2)
2      -      3        21    (24-3)
3      +      8        29    (21+8)
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Comment: Where's the common column???  Without a common column, you can't join the 2 tables.

Comment: You have simplified this so much it isn't answerable. You need something to use for ordering. You need something to join on. But in the end this is just a running total made a little bit odd by the flow column. But that is trivial to deal with. Just requires a few silly string manipulations to turn your string into a usable formula.

Comment: Added common row.

Comment: still isn't enough for even a recursive cte i don't think

Comment: Are you actually using sql 2008? There are ways to do this but with 2012+ it is simpler and more performant.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some kind of ordering column to the first table. Otherwise it doesn't make sense. I decided to add the extra column `seq` that seves this purpose.

Therefore, with the following data:

```
create table flow (
  stockid int,
  seq int,
  flow char(1),
  stock int
);

insert into flow (stockid, seq, flow, stock) values (1, 10, '+', 2);
insert into flow (stockid, seq, flow, stock) values (1, 11, '-', 3);
insert into flow (stockid, seq, flow, stock) values (1, 12, '+', 8);

create table stock (
  id int,
  instock int
);

insert into stock (id, instock) values (1, 22);
insert into stock (id, instock) values (2, 51);
insert into stock (id, instock) values (3, 92);
```

The query is:

```
select s.id, f.seq, f.flow, f.stock,
    s.instock + 
      sum(case when f.flow = '+' then 1 else -1 end * f.stock)
      over(partition by s.id order by f.seq) as sol
  from stock s
  left join flow f on f.stockid = s.id;
```

Result:

```
id  seq     flow    stock   sol          
--  ------  ------  ------  ------
1   10      +       2       24    
1   11      -       3       21    
1   12      +       8       29    
2   <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>
3   <null>  <null>  <null>  <null>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008, you are stuck with `apply` for calculating the cumulative sum:

```
select t1.*, tt1.stock + t2.instock
from t1 cross apply
     (select sum(case when flow = '+' then tt1.sock else - tt1.stock end) as stock
      from t1 tt1
      where tt1.id <= t1.id
     )  tt1 cross join
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from t2
      order by id
     ) t2;
```