# How do you Window.partitionBy over a range or condition?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, partition-by

I have some data that is ordered by dateTime, and I want to add up the values based on another column(1 or 0). HOWEVER, I need it done such that it only sums the values up to 5 seconds after. How do I do this?

ex Table

```py
|ID  |GPS_TimeStamp         |overG|
---------------------------------
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:05.1 |1    |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:06.3 |0    |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:08.4 |1    |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:10.0 |1    |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:11.1 |0    |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:12.2 |0    |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:13.8 |1    |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:16.1 |0    |
---------------------------------
```

my pseudo code that doesnt work is as below

```py
myData = myData.withColumn("overG-sum5Seconds", 
   sum(col("overG")).over(Window.partitionBy(
      "GPS_TimeStamp"
   ).orderBy("GPS_TimeStamp").rangeBetween(0, Window.currentRow+timedelta(seconds=5))
   )
```

for a result that looks like

```py
|ID  |GPS_TimeStamp         |overG|overG-sum5Seconds|
---------------------------------------------------
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:05.1 |1    |3                |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:06.3 |0    |2                |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:08.4 |1    |3                |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:10.0 |1    |2                |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:11.1 |0    |1                |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:12.2 |0    |1                |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:13.8 |1    |1                |
|aa  |2019-08-01 00:18:16.1 |0    |0                |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I cannot use lag or lead because not every second is in the list. So it has to be a condition based on GPS_TimeStamp.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer after visiting a few sites.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/time-series-moving-average-apache-pyspark-laurent-weichberger

Turns out I wanted a sliding avg/sum

```py
myData = myData.withColumn("unix", (unix_timestamp("GPS_TimeStamp"))+ expr("substr(GPS_TimeStamp,instr(GPS_TimeStamp, '.'))"))
w = (Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("unix")).rangeBetween(0, 5))
myData = myData.withColumn('rolling_sum', sum("overG").over(w))
```

Answer (score 0):

Window Function Frame can solve your problem. [Window Frames](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html)
In short, all you have to do is the **conditional cumulative sum** you can refer this answer as well, [How to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum/2120639).

Comment: Can you please provide code? Those links all use 

ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW, 

but I need something like

rangeBetween(CURRENT ROW AND (CURRENT ROW)+5seconds)

Comment: Also, I'm looking at more of a sliding window sum not a rolling cumulative.