# How to get cumulative sum in SQL Server (Z=Z+A+B-C)

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

I want to create cumulative sum in table ( Commul_table) in SQL  such as
Z=Z+ (A+B-C )

[image: Commul_table i want compute value of Z]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Comment: no , because i want to add and subtract more than one cell in each row in column Z , (Z=Z+A+B-C)

Comment: `sum(a+b-c) over (order by Id rows unbounded preceding)`

Comment: The sample data seems to have nothing to do with the calculations you are suggesting.  The second `z` value should be 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `analytic function`  in this case with `rows unbounded preceding` (to get sum values before current row)

```
Select id, A,B,C,sum(A+B-C) over(order by Id rows unbounded preceding) as Z
From Table
```

Comment: Ali Jamal, do you try query?)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's run.

Comment: If it is run, please check answer -  just mark it as solution)

Answer (score 1):

It's still a *Cumulative Sum*, just based on a calculation on three columns:

```
sum(a+b-c) over (order by Id rows unbounded preceding)
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0829d67b65a819766bee7566cf033abf)

Comment: thinks for help

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering to point out that the window frame clause is not needed in most databases.  Assuming that the `id` is unique:

```
select ct.*, sum(a + b - c) over (order by id) as z
from Commul_table;
```

If `id` can be duplicated, please explain what you want for the results.  The above also assumes that `a`, `b`, and `c` are never `NULL`.  If they can be, then you want to substitute `0` for them:

```
select ct.*,
       sum(coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0) - coalesce(c, 0)) over (order by id) as z
from Commul_table;
```