# How to sum different columns and use the sum result set into another column sum using SQL Server dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to achieve something as mentioned below

```
Row_Num    ID    Total Time     Timeout
----------------------------------------
1         33       120             1
2         34       120            121
3         35       121            241
4         36       145            362
```

using sql queries, i would like try to find the timeout from column, based on previous row total time. for every row_number 1 , timeout should be 1

eg: 1+120=121, 3rd row, 121+120=242 so on..

please help me in this regard. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2120544/2029983)

Comment: It is, just the first value is replaced with `1`, @TimBiegeleisen . 1 + 120 + 121 + 145 = 387`

Comment: How does 121  + 120 = 242?  How is 387 calculated?

Comment: `1+120+121 = 242` @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Gordon sir, second row timeout is calculated based on first row timeout and total time, third row timeout is sum of second row timeout and total time.. in this way I need to get using sql query

Comment: How do you get the value for the last row? 121+241 = 362 not 352.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a cumulative `SUM`, but you replace the first value with `1`:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE RowNum WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE TotalTime END) OVER (ORDER BY RowNum) AS TimeOut
```

For example:

```sql
SELECT RowNum,
       TotalTime,
       SUM(CASE RowNum WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE TotalTime END) OVER (ORDER BY RowNum) AS TimeOut
FROM (VALUES(1,120),
            (2,120),
            (3,121),
            (4,145))V(RowNum,TotalTime);
```

Returns:

```
RowNum      TotalTime   TimeOut
----------- ----------- -----------
1           120         1
2           120         121
3           121         242
4           145         387
```

---

Appears the OP has changed their requirements, and the expected results are different now (/sigh). This would be:

```sql
SELECT RowNum,
       TotalTime,
       1 + ISNULL(SUM(TotalTime) OVER (ORDER BY RowNum ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS TimeOut
FROM (VALUES(1,120),
            (2,120),
            (3,121),
            (4,145))V(RowNum,TotalTime);
```

This, however, assumes that the OP's latest expected results are wrong, as `241+121=362` not `352`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract out the first value and replace it with 1:

```
select t.*,
       1 + sum(total_time) over (order by row_num) - first_value(total_time) over (order by row_num) as total_time
from t;
```

Comment: @Larnu . . . I realize based on your comment that the arithmetic in the question is way off and the question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: All i need is second row timeout is calculated based on first row timeout and total time, third row timeout is sum of second row timeout and total time.. in this way I need to get using sql query