# Calculate cumulative product value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have the following database table:

```
Date        Return  Index
01-01-2020  0.1     Null 
01-02-2020  0.2     Null
01-03-2020  0.3     Null
```

I would like to update the Index value using the following formula:

```
Index = (Previous_Month_Index * Return) + Previous_Month_Index (Use 100 for Previous_Month_Index for the first month)
```

Expected Result: (Index to be calculated order by Date asc)

```
Date        Return  Index
01-01-2020  0.1     110  -- (100 + 10)
01-02-2020  0.2     132  -- (110 + (110 * 0.20)) = 110 + 22 = 132
01-03-2020  0.3     171.6  -- (132 + (132 * 0.30)) = 132 + 39.6 = 171.6
```

How can I do this using SQL? I tried the following query but getting an error:

> Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

```
--first, load the sample data to a temp table
select *
into #t
from 
(
  values
  ('2020-01-01', 0.10),
  ('2020-02-01', 0.20),
  ('2020-03-01', 0.30)
) d ([Date], [Return]);

--next, calculate cumulative product
select *, CumFactor = cast(exp(sum(log(case when ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by [Date] ASC)  = 1 then 100 * [Return] else [Return] end)) over (order by [Date])) as float) from #t;

drop table #t
```

Comment: Thanks @DaleK for updating it.

Comment: You can use [LAG(Index) OVER (ORDER BY Date)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of a CTE or `ROW_NUMBER` to get the "previous" Index by date. You can specify a default value too, eg `LAG(Index,1,100)` to specify a "previous" value for the first row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking mathematically, the result that you want is equivalent to this product:

```
100 * (1 + a1) * (1 + a2) * (1 + a3) * ....
```

where a1, a2, a3 are the values of the column `[Return]`.

This product can be obtained by:

```
100 * EXP(SUM(LOG(1 + [Return])))
```

and you can do this in sql like this:

```
SELECT *, 
       100 * EXP(SUM(LOG(1 + [Return])) OVER (ORDER BY [Date])) [Index]
FROM #t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e0673159db60e0e863b3ec6a3537925).

Answer (score 2):

A recursive CTE might be the simplest approach:

```
with tt as (
      select row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum, date, ret
      from t
     ),
     cte as (
      select seqnum, date, ret, convert(float, (1 + ret) * 100) as runningTotal
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.seqnum, tt.date, tt.ret, convert(float, (1 + tt.ret) * cte.runningTotal)
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c05fb239cd9e0c3adcc3b9c2a1b72c36) is a db<>fiddle.