# SQL - get rid of the nested aggregate select

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table `Payment`, which for example tracks the amount of money user puts into account, simplified as

```
===================================
Id | UserId |  Amount |   PayDate |
===================================
 1 |     42 |      11 |  01.02.99 |
 2 |     42 |      31 |  05.06.99 |
 3 |     42 |      21 |  04.11.99 |
 4 |     24 |      12 |  05.11.99 |
```

What is need is to receive a table with balance before payment moment, eg:

```
===============================================
Id | UserId |   Amount |   PayDate |  Balance |
===============================================
 1 |     42 |       11 |  01.02.99 |        0 |
 2 |     42 |       31 |  05.06.99 |       11 |
 3 |     42 |       21 |  04.11.99 |       42 |
 4 |     24 |       12 |  05.11.99 |        0 |
```

Currently the select statement looks something like

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    UserId,
    Amount,
    PaidDate,
    (SELECT sum(amount) FROM Payments nestedp 
      WHERE nestedp.UserId = outerp.UserId AND
            nestedp.PayDate < outerp.PayDate) as Balance
FROM
    Payments outerp
```

How can I rewrite this select to get rid of the nested aggregate selection? The database in question is SQL Server 2019.

Comment: You have the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

Comment: Yes, since SQL Server 2012 SQL Server has supported "rolling/cumulative aggregates" with the use of the `OVER` clause.

Comment: 20 years after Y2k. NO ONE should be using 2-digit years for anything.

Comment: @SMor, except for a simplified example on stackoverflow, maybe?

Comment: How does that specific simplification benefit anyone? (Other than the obvious "I didn't have to type two characters.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to other participants' leads I came up with a query that (seems) to work:

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    UserId,
    Amount,
    PayDate,
    COALESCE(sum(Amount) over (partition by UserId 
                                order by PayDate 
                                rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as Balance
FROM
    Payments
ORDER BY
    UserId, PayDate
```

Lots of related examples can be found [here](https://docs.teradata.com/r/756LNiPSFdY%7E4JcCCcR5Cw/quvs_Gi2rQI8mhPkqjDwwQ)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cte with some custom logic to handle this type of problem.

```
WITH PaymentCte
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Id
            ) AS RowId
        ,Id
        ,UserId
        ,PayDate
        ,Amount
        ,SUM(Amount) OVER (
            PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Id
            ) AS Balance
    FROM Payment
    )
SELECT X.Id
    ,X.UserId
    ,X.Amount
    ,X.PayDate
    ,Y.Balance
FROM PaymentCte x
INNER JOIN PaymentCte y ON x.userId = y.UserId
    AND X.RowId = Y.RowId + 1

UNION

SELECT X.Id
    ,X.UserId
    ,X.Amount
    ,X.PayDate
    ,0 AS Balance
FROM PaymentCte x
WHERE X.RowId = 1
```

This provides the desired output

---

[image]

---

Comment: What if id and paydate not necessarily go in order? Change to `SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY PayDate ) AS Balance`?

Comment: @Timofeus Did you run after updating this in above query at your end? I don't think it will give desired output which you have mentioned in your output table

Comment: @Timofeus If you want Order By PayDate as your order by column for Sum then output balance for Id=3 will be 63

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using `lag` with a cumulative `sum`

```
 with b as (
  select * , isnull(lag(amount) over (partition by userid order by id),0) Amt
    from t
 )
 select Id, UserId, Amount, PayDate, 
   Sum(Amt) over (partition by userid order by id) Balance
 from b
 order by Id
```

Comment: Did you test this? I tried running this and I am not getting 0 as Balance for Id 1 and 4

Comment: @ishantkaushik Yes of course, it produces your desired results, see [this example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcf41859454261bd80256407c6881819)