# Use a value from a line before in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a query with a few columns of a table and now I want a new column that offsets the value of two columns with the value of the row above. The first line is the base value for the calculation.

| ID | date | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-11 | 12000 | NULL |
| 2 | 2022-02-11 | 500 | NULL |
| 3 | 2022-02-11 | NULL | 200 |
| 4 | 2022-03-11 | NULL | 400 |

So in this example 12000 is the first line therefore the base value.
The second line should take the base value (from the line above) and add the 500. So the result is 12500 in this line.
The third line should take the result from above 12500 and subtract the 200 from v2. So the result in this line is 12300. And so on..
The formula is therefore: result (from line above) + v1 - v2

What I expect is this:

| ID | date | val1 | val2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-11 | 12000 | NULL | 12000 |
| 2 | 2022-02-11 | 500 | NULL | 12500 |
| 3 | 2022-02-11 | NULL | 200 | 12300 |
| 4 | 2022-03-11 | NULL | 400 | 11900 |

The query so far is:

```
SELECT ID, date, val1, val2
FROM Table
ORDER BY ID
```

How can I get the result column to this select-query?

Could anyone help me please?

I didn't really try anything because I absolutely don't know how to get a value from a line above.

Comment: This looks more like you want cumulative aggregation, not the use the value from the last row.

Comment: look up LEAD and LAG functions

Comment: I think you can find the answer to your question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SUM()` function to do a running total over the entire query results. Here I'm using the `SUM()` and specifying `val1 - val2` inside the function. Reference learning material: https://codingsight.com/calculating-running-total-with-over-clause-and-partition-by-clause-in-sql-server/

```
CREATE TABLE dataTable (
  ID int not null
  , [date] datetime not null
  , val1 int null
  , val2 int null
);

INSERT INTO dataTable (ID, [date], val1, val2)
VALUES (1, '2022-01-11', 12000, null)
  , (2, '2022-02-11', 500, null)
  , (3, '2022-02-11', null, 200)
  , (4, '2022-03-11', null, 400)
;

SELECT ID, date, val1, val2
  , SUM (ISNULL(val1,0) - ISNULL(val2,0)) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS result
FROM dataTable
ORDER BY ID
```

| ID | date | val1 | val2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-11 00:00:00.000 | 12000 | *null* | 12000 |
| 2 | 2022-02-11 00:00:00.000 | 500 | *null* | 12500 |
| 3 | 2022-02-11 00:00:00.000 | *null* | 200 | 12300 |
| 4 | 2022-03-11 00:00:00.000 | *null* | 400 | 11900 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tQ-puh1N)