# Apply cumulative discount to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

To the table I need to calculate `DISCOUNT_AMOUNT` and `AMOUNT_REST` as follows in the formula view. For every `NAME` there is a unique amount repeated in every row, but the discount isnt `AMOUNT*DISCOUNT%` in all rows, only the first discount order by ascending `DATE`. The next discounts  for the same `NAME` are applied to the `AMOUNT_REST`.

A way to solve this in SQL Server language?

```
select [NAME], [AMOUNT], [DISCOUNT%], [DATE]--, DISCOUNT_AMOUNT, AMOUNT_REST
FROM [Table]
order by [NAME], [DATE] asc
```

This is what a I want:

| [NAME] | [AMOUNT] | [DATE] (dd-MM-yyyy) | [DISCOUNT%] | [DISCOUNT_AMOUNT] | [AMOUNT_REST] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | $100 | 01-01-2023 | 4% | $4,0 | $96,0 |
| Peter | $100 | 02-01-2023 | 20% | $19,2 | $76,8 |
| Peter | $100 | 03-01-2023 | 5% | $3,8 | $73,0 |
| John | $500 | 01-01-2023 | 40% | $200,0 | $300,0 |
| John | $500 | 02-01-2023 | 3% | $9,0 | $291,0 |
| Sara | $200 | 01-01-2023 | 9% | $18,0 | $182,0 |
| Sara | $200 | 02-01-2023 | 10% | $18,2 | $163,8 |

This is the Excel-manual way to do it

| [NAME] | [AMOUNT] | [DATE] (dd-MM-yyyy) | [DISCOUNT%] | [DISCOUNT_AMOUNT] | [AMOUNT_REST] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 100 | 44927 | 0,04 | B2*D2 | B2*(1-D2) |
| Peter | 100 | 44928 | 0,2 | F2*D3 | F2*(1-D3) |
| Peter | 100 | 44929 | 0,05 | F3*D4 | F3*(1-D4) |
| John | 500 | 44927 | 0,4 | B5*D5 | B5*(1-D5) |
| John | 500 | 44928 | 0,03 | F5*D6 | F5*(1-D6) |
| Sara | 200 | 44927 | 0,09 | B7*D7 | B7*(1-D7) |
| Sara | 200 | 44928 | 0,1 | F7*D8 | F7*(1-D8) |

Comment: There are "cumulative SQL" questions which show a general approach - for example: [How to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2120544/12567365) shows some different approaches (and you would have to replace their `sum` with the discount calculation you need). There are also more examples [in these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=cumulative+sql+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @andrewJames: that's a cumulative *discount*, which seems like a more complicated beast than just a window `sum`. There are probably duplicates available, but likely there are rarest and harder to adapt from one use case to anther.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there might be a mathematical approach to compute the cumulative discount using window functions, this seems more easily approached with a recursive query:

```
with 
    data as (
        select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by date) rn
        from mytable t
    ),
    rcte as (
        select name, amount, date, discount_pct, rn,
            amount * discount_pct       as discount_amount,
            amount * (1 - discount_pct) as rest_amount
        from data
        where rn = 1
        union all
        select r.name, r.amount, d.date, d.discount_pct, d.rn
            r.rest_amount * d.discount_pct,
            r.rest_amount * (1 - d.discount_pct)              
        from rcte r
        inner join data d on d.name = r.name and d.rn = r.rn + 1
    )
select * from rcte
```

The first CTE, `data`, enumerates the rows of each `name`. Then `rcte` starts from the first row of each partition and iterates, basically applying the same computation logic as the Excel formulas in your question.

Comment: You got it right, code works. But sadly this code doesn't run for big data sets (server performance i guess). Maybe should try some Python...

Answer (score 0):

Math:
log (a+b) = log(a) * log(b), so we can calculate exp(sum(log(col))

https://dbfiddle.uk/IZMXyxUq

```
with data(name, amount, dat, discount) as (
    select 'Peter', 100, convert(DATE, '01-01-2023',105), 4  union all
    select 'Peter', 100, convert(DATE,'02-01-2023',105), 20  union all
    select 'Peter', 100, convert(DATE,'03-01-2023',105),5  union all
    select 'John', 500, convert(DATE,'01-01-2023',105),40  union all
    select 'John', 500, convert(DATE,'02-01-2023',105),3  union all
    select 'Sara', 200, convert(DATE,'01-01-2023',105),9  union all
    select 'Sara', 200, convert(DATE,'02-01-2023',105),10  -- union all
),
rdata as (
    select * from (
        select d.name, d.amount, d.dat, d.discount / 100.0 as discount, 
            log(1.0 - (d.discount / 100.0)) as ln_rest_factor, 
        row_number() over(partition by name order by dat) as rn
        from data d
    ) d
)
select name, amount, discount, coalesce(lag(discount_rest) over(partition by name order by rn),amount) - discount_rest as discount_amount, discount_rest 
from (
    select name, amount, discount, round(amount * exp(sum_factor),2) as discount_rest, rn
    from (
        select name, amount, dat, discount, rn, ln_rest_factor,
            sum(ln_rest_factor) over(partition by name order by rn) as sum_factor
        from rdata
    ) d
) d
order by name, rn
;
```