# Number of records by current week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, cumulative-sum

My query returns all currently open records and here is a sample:

| BDC_ID | BDC_CREATE_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 2660830 | 5/1/2023 |
| 2660846 | 5/3/2023 |
| 2678805 | 5/3/2023 |
| 2698805 | 5/4/2023 |
| 2778545 | 5/8/2023 |
| 2788869 | 5/9/2023 |
| 2798112 | 5/10/2023 |
| 2845531 | 5/15/2023 |
| 2849555 | 5/17/2023 |

I am trying to show the ROLLING TOTAL of open records by week, starting with 5/1 being week 1.

So, I would expect the output to look something like this:

| WEEK | ROLLING TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 (5/1-5/7) | 4 |
| 2 (5/8-5/14) | 7 |
| 3 (5/15-5/21) | 9 |

Any insight would be great, thank you.

Comment: Have you got a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)?

Comment: Yes, I have a date dimension table

Comment: Get yourself a calendar table and join this result set to your calendar table so you can aggregate the totals by week. Once you have weekly totals then you can cumulatively sum those results using window function `SUM(yourtotalcolumn) OVER (ORDER BY your_week_number_column ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` [Like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13331102/2221001)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by:

- grouping on year and week of year over date
- aggregating on min/max dates, and computing a running sum, on aggregated counts, by ordering on min_date, for the specified groups

```
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(BDC_CREATE_DATE), ' - ', DATEADD(DAY, 6, MIN(BDC_CREATE_DATE))) AS WEEK,
       SUM(COUNT(BDC_ID)) OVER(ORDER BY MIN(BDC_CREATE_DATE))    AS ROLLING_TOTAL
FROM tab
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, BDC_CREATE_DATE),
         DATEPART(WEEK, BDC_CREATE_DATE)
```

If your `MIN(BDC_CREATE_DATE)` does not correspond to the initial part of the week, we can recreate the beginning boundary exploiting the weekday (credits to [@LHA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3018377/lha) for the smart suggestion).

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEADD(DAY, 2 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, MIN(BDC_CREATE_DATE)), MIN(BDC_CREATE_DATE)), 
              ' - ', 
              DATEADD(DAY, 8 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, MAX(BDC_CREATE_DATE)), MAX(BDC_CREATE_DATE))) AS WEEK,
       SUM(COUNT(BDC_ID)) OVER(ORDER BY MIN(BDC_CREATE_DATE))    AS ROLLING_TOTAL
FROM tab
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, BDC_CREATE_DATE),
         DATEPART(WEEK, BDC_CREATE_DATE)
```

**Output**:

| WEEK | ROLLING_TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 - 2023-05-07 | 4 |
| 2023-05-08 - 2023-05-14 | 7 |
| 2023-05-15 - 2023-05-21 | 9 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cs1hr9Su).

Comment: The week id should include the first and the last day of the week ( 6 days difference)

Comment: Actually noticed it was easier than I thought to recreate the ranges.

Comment: This works, but only because the first day of each week is present in the records included in his example. If the first day of the week was not present, this would not work. For example, changing `5/1/2023` to `5/2/2023` would yield a result where the first week shows `2023-05-02 - 2023-05-07`. If the assumption the first day of the week will always be present is true, then this could work. But I assume that is likely not a good assumption.

Comment: The issue doesn't apply to only the first week, it applies to all weeks where the first day might be missing from the dataset. For example, if the date `5/8/2023` or `5/15/2023` were simply missing from the included records, this would then yield a result where the weeks would then show incorrectly.

Comment: If this data was generated by employees working on a given day, consider what would happen on a Monday holiday where no employees worked? This query would then show incorrect and overlapping weeks.

Comment: Voted. This solution is almost correct. You can use thoses SQL functions to determine the first and the last date of a week based on a date:  DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, BDC_CREATE_DATE), BDC_CREATE_DATE)    AND  DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, BDC_CREATE_DATE), BDC_CREATE_DATE)

Comment: @LHA Just requires to apply MIN(date), MAX(date) to your code, and that would definitely solve the assumption made in first place. That's definitely a smart solution to that.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Microsoft's documentation on [SET DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and how you can can use that to control the behaviour of some date functions like [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). You can use `SET DATEFIRST` to set which day is considered the first day of the week.

For example, the below query uses that to set the first day of the week to Monday and then is able to use the `DATEPART` function like normal. This paired with `DENSE_RANK` to generate the week number and `SUM` to calculate the rolling total generate the results you are looking for:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1; /*monday*/ 

DECLARE @BdcList_TBL TABLE(
    BDC_ID numeric(18,0) NOT NULL 
    ,BDC_CREATE_DATE date NOT NULL 
); 
INSERT INTO @BdcList_TBL (BDC_ID,BDC_CREATE_DATE) VALUES
(2660830,'2023-05-01') 
,(2660846,'2023-05-03') 
,(2678805,'2023-05-03') 
,(2698805,'2023-05-04') 
,(2778545,'2023-05-08') 
,(2788869,'2023-05-09') 
,(2798112,'2023-05-10') 
,(2845531,'2023-05-15') 
,(2849555,'2023-5-17'); 

SELECT 
    CONCAT(CAST(all_weeks.WEEK_NUMBER AS varchar(2)),' (',DATEPART(MONTH,all_weeks.WEEK_START),'/',DATEPART(DAY,all_weeks.WEEK_START),'-',DATEPART(MONTH,all_weeks.WEEK_END),'/',DATEPART(DAY,all_weeks.WEEK_END),')') AS [WEEK]
    ,all_weeks.BDC_COUNT AS ROLLING_TOTAL
FROM 
    /*just doing a subquery for readability in final select for formatting the dates*/
    (SELECT 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEK,bdc_list.BDC_CREATE_DATE)) AS WEEK_NUMBER 
        ,SUM(COUNT(1)) OVER(ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEK,bdc_list.BDC_CREATE_DATE)) AS BDC_COUNT
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, MIN(bdc_list.BDC_CREATE_DATE)), CAST(MIN(bdc_list.BDC_CREATE_DATE) AS DATE)) AS WEEK_START
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, MIN(bdc_list.BDC_CREATE_DATE)), CAST(MIN(bdc_list.BDC_CREATE_DATE) AS DATE)) AS WEEK_END 
    FROM 
        @BdcList_TBL AS bdc_list
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART(WEEK,BDC_CREATE_DATE)) AS all_weeks
ORDER BY 
    all_weeks.WEEK_NUMBER;
```

Having a custom date dimension table of sorts would certainly make it easier, but using `SET DATEFIRST` makes this not much more complex than your average windowed aggregate query.

Hopefully points you in the right direction, and good luck with Epic :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with const as (
    -- using a fixed date reference
    -- this could easily be a parameter, subquery, or relative date calculation
    select cast('20230501' as date) as basedate
), data as (
    select *, datediff(day, basedate, BDC_CREATE_DATE) / 7 as wk
    from T t cross join const
)
select
    wk, dateadd(day, wk * 7, basedate), dateadd(day, wk * 7 + 6, basedate),
    sum(count(*)) over (order by wk) as ROLLING_TOTAL
from data
group by wk;
```

This makes no use of SQL Server week functions. It's just using an arbitrary date as a starting point. There is no need to assume any particular dates within a week are present.

Answer (score 0):

Count the rows from the table group by the date of preceding Monday and the first Monday date gets 1 for ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Monday date).

```
WITH MONDAYS AS(SELECT DATEADD(DAY,(2-7-(@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,BDC_CREATE_DATE))%7)%7,BDC_CREATE_DATE)MONDAY,COUNT(*)COUNTER
FROM BDC_TABLE GROUP BY DATEADD(DAY,(2-7-(@@DATEFIRST+DATEPART(WEEKDAY,BDC_CREATE_DATE))%7)%7,BDC_CREATE_DATE))
SELECT CONCAT(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY MONDAY),'(',MONTH(MONDAY),'/',DAY(MONDAY),'-',MONTH(DATEADD(DAY,6,MONDAY)),'/',DAY(DATEADD(DAY,6,MONDAY)),')')WEEK,SUM(COUNTER)OVER(ORDER BY MONDAY)[ROLLING TOTAL]
FROM MONDAYS
```

Comment: @DaleK Could you please stop changing the answers i have posted? It makes it very difficult for me. If you do not like the format then simply ignore the answer. Thanks in advance.