# Cumulative sum of a counted column

Tags: sql, window-functions, cumulative-sum, confluence

I'm trying to count from a table and then sum the counted column numbers into a new column in Confluence with Table Transformer plugin.

So far, what I've got is:

| YDT | Daily Execution |
| --- | --- |
| Sep 04, 2023 | 10 |
| Sep 05, 2023 | 65 |
| Sep 06, 2023 | 55 |
| Sep 07, 2023 | 64 |
| Sep 08, 2023 | 69 |

by running the following SQL:

```
SELECT T1.'Due' as 'YDT',
       COUNT('Due') AS 'Daily Execution'
FROM T*
GROUP BY Due 
ORDER BY YDT ASC
```

and I'm expecting this:

| YDT | Daily Execution | Planned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sep 04, 2023 | 10 | 10 |
| Sep 05, 2023 | 65 | 75 |
| Sep 06, 2023 | 55 | 130 |
| Sep 07, 2023 | 64 | 194 |
| Sep 08, 2023 | 69 | 263 |

After several attempts I still can't reach my goal, can someone to help on this case?

---

### **Solution：**

Just figured out the solution to reach my goal

[image: Structure]

1. Use Table Transformer plugin to Query YDT Column and Count issues according to YDT date in Inner Upper table by using following SQL

   SELECT 'Due' as 'YDT', COUNT('Due') AS 'Daily Execution'
   FROM T*
   GROUP BY Due
   ORDER BY YDT ASC
2. Use Table Excerpt to re-use previous data
3. Add Table Excerpt Include plugin to copy Inner Upper table to Inner Lower Table Transformer plugin and Sum Daily Execution column by using following SQL

   SELECT 'YDT',
   SUM (TT2.'Daily Execution') AS 'Planned'
   FROM T1 AS TT1
   JOIN T1 AS TT2 on TT1.'YDT' >= TT2.'YDT'
   GROUP BY TT1.'YDT'
   ORDER BY TT1.'YDT'
4. Use Table Transformer plugin in external to lookup tables by YDT column

   SELECT * FROM T1 OUTER JOIN T* ON T1.'YDT' = T*.'YDT'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @dcolazin Thank you to provide this link but it looks like that does not help

Comment: @jarlh Sorry, I'm not sure which DBMS used in this case since I'm using Table Transformer plugin in Confluence

Comment: I was just wondering, I'd expect syntax error for the above query.

Answer (score 0):

**As much as I can understand your question, it looks like you want to add a new column to your table that shows the cumulative sum of the ‘Daily Execution’ column. You can achieve this by using a subquery in your SQL statement. Here’s an example of how you can modify your SQL statement to achieve the desired result:**

```
SELECT T1.'Due' as 'YDT', COUNT('Due') AS 'Daily Execution', (SELECT SUM(COUNT('Due')) FROM T* WHERE Due <= T1.Due) AS 'Planned'
FROM T*
GROUP BY Due
ORDER BY YDT ASC
```

This should give you the desired result with the new ‘Planned’ column showing the cumulative sum of the ‘Daily Execution’ column.

I hope this helps brother...

Comment: Thx bro, but I've got Parse error on line 1: ... AS `Planned` FROM T* GROUP BY Due ORDER -----------------------^ Expecting 'LITERAL', 'BRALITERAL', 'EOF', 'WITH', 'COMMA', 'AS', 'LPAR', 'RPAR', 'PIVOT', 'UNPIVOT', 'DOT',…

Comment: Try replacing T* with the actual name of your table in the FROM clause and see if that resolves the issue.
In SQL, the ‘*’ character is used as a wildcard to select all columns from a table. However, it cannot be used in the FROM clause to specify the table name.
The error message indicates that there is a parse error on line 1, and the parser is expecting a ‘LITERAL’ or other token instead of the ‘*’ character.

Comment: Oops, Parse error fixed but no luck with TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'COUNT(Due)'). It looks like the 'Table Transformer' plugin does not like nested Select statement