Recursive CTE returns duplicate rows
In SQL Server, I have a Transactions and a TransactionDetails table.
Transactions table has the following columns:
TransactionId
Amount
ProcessedDate
TransactionDetailsId

TransactionDetails table has following columns:
TransactionDetailsId
AdvanceId

I have initial values for ClearedBalance and PendingBalance.
I need to write a query to select from Transactions table starting from specific transaction to all transactions down which has ProcessedDate greater  than starting transaction. This query should also calculate running balances for each transaction.
I chose to to it using this recursive CTE:
-- Here we get current balances for advance
DECLARE @InitialPendingBalance  DECIMAL(18, 2) = 1000000;
DECLARE @InitialClearedBalance DECIMAL(18, 2) = 1000000;

WITH RecursiveBalances AS 
(
    -- Base case: Start with the new transaction
    SELECT
        t.TransactionId,
        td.AdvanceId,
        t.Amount,
        CAST(@InitialPendingBalance + t.Amount AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS PendingBalance,
        CAST(@InitialClearedBalance + t.Amount AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS ClearedBalance,
        t.ProcessedDate
    FROM 
        [transaction].Transactions t
    JOIN
        [transaction].TransactionDetails td ON t.TransactionDetailsId = td.TransactionDetailId 
    WHERE 
        t.TransactionId = 8743

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursion part
    SELECT
        t.TransactionId,
        td.AdvanceId,
        t.Amount,
        CAST(rb.PendingBalance + t.Amount AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS PendingBalance,
        CAST(rb.ClearedBalance + t.Amount AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS ClearedBalance,
        t.ProcessedDate
    FROM
        [transaction].Transactions t
    JOIN
        [transaction].TransactionDetails td ON t.TransactionDetailsId = td.TransactionDetailId 
                                            AND td.AdvanceId = 100000800
    JOIN 
        RecursiveBalances rb ON t.ProcessedDate > rb.ProcessedDate
)
SELECT
    TransactionId, 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
    RecursiveBalances 
GROUP BY
    TransactionId 
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*);

This CTE returns starting transaction and transactions happened after this transaction but it contains duplicates. Number of duplicates increases exponentially.
select 
    TransactionId, 
    count(*) 
from RecursiveBalances 
group by TransactionId 
order by count(*)

this query returns this result:



TransactionId
Count




8743
1


8744
1


8767
2


8777
2


8783
6


8789
12


8794
12


8799
36


8803
36


8809
108


8813
108



How can I solve this duplication issue?

Please add a complete minimal reproducible example contaning the table structure (preferrable as CREATE TABLE ... statement), example data, expected result and current result.

and what is the sample data that was used to generate this result ?

There's no proper recursion clause. JOIN RecursiveBalances rb ON t.ProcessedDate > rb.ProcessedDate matches every row with a previous date, whether it's related or not. You don't need a recursive CTE to create a running total anyway. You can use COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY TransactionID ORDER BY ProcessedDate)

What's the original data and what are you trying to calculate? The running balance by account ?

Are you sure you intended to have WHERE t.TransactionId = 8743 and the UNION ALL here?

I agree that you really don't need to be using recursion here but to answer your specific question: The "duplicates" arise because each recursion retrieves all following rows, not just the next following row. If you had transactions [A, B, C, D] with A selected by the base query, the first recursion will yield [A+B, A+C, A+D]. The second recursion [A+B+C. A+B+D, A+C+D]. The third will yield [A+B+C+D]. This yields a total of 8 results - not duplicates, but A plus all combinations of [B, C, D].

What you likely really need is (1) Logic to select the initial transaction (t1). (2) A join or CROSS APPLY (t2) that all related transactions on t2.ProcessedDate  >= t1.ProcessedDate (and other criteria). Calculate the running totals in the select list as @InitialPendingBalance + SUM(t2.Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY t1.transactionId ORDER BY t2.ProcessedDate) AS PendingBalance and similar for ClearedBalance. If t2.ProcessedDate might have repeated values, you may need to add ...ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING ROW AND CURRENT ROW to the OVER(...) clause.

Agree with @TN. Recursive CTE is the problem. If you need to compute cumulative sum, then take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120544/how-to-get-cumulative-sum

@TN, main objective in this task is that whenever new transaction added for specific advance and if transaction process date is in the past (here we assume that it is in the past) we need to fetch all transactions of same advance which happened after this newly added transaction and recalculate balances for them. Anchor part of recursive CTE is about getting newly added transaction and recursive part should get transactions happened after this. Each transactions running balance is calculated using previous transaction's running balance.

This recursive cte should return list of transactions including newly added and other transactions happened after this and their running balances. @PanagiotisKanavos.

Explaining the problem in terms of CTEs doesn't help and only confuses people. Post the tables, sample data and the desired output instead of describing them in comments. You don't need recursion to find previous rows in a set, that's what the OVER(PARTITION BY ...ORDER BY ...) clause is for. You can use that with aggregation functions like SUM, COUNT etc.

You could use a single CTE to get the desired results if I understood the question correctly like below:
;WITH RunningBalances AS (
    SELECT 
        t.TransactionId,
        t.Amount,
        t.ProcessedDate,
        td.AdvanceId,
        -- Running ClearedBalance
        SUM(t.Amount) OVER (ORDER BY t.ProcessedDate) AS ClearedBalance,
        -- Running PendingBalance
        SUM(t.Amount) OVER (ORDER BY t.ProcessedDate) AS PendingBalance,
        -- Number of transactions
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.ProcessedDate) AS CumulativeTransactionCount
    FROM 
        dbo.Transactions t
    JOIN 
        dbo.TransactionDetails td ON t.TransactionDetailsId = td.TransactionDetailsId
    WHERE 
        t.ProcessedDate > (
            SELECT ProcessedDate 
            FROM Transactions 
            WHERE TransactionId = 8743  --@StartingTransactionId
        )
)
SELECT TransactionId, Amount, ProcessedDate, AdvanceId, ClearedBalance, PendingBalance, CumulativeTransactionCount
FROM RunningBalances
ORDER BY ProcessedDate;

